# Dark grey residue from newly purchased stainless steel kitchen items?

Tags: food-safety, equipment

I have had this happen a few times now. What happens is that I purchase a new kitchen item made of stainless steel. When cleaning it, I find out that there is some kind of dark grey residue that comes off of it. The items that have done this are supposed to be used to cook or they come into contact with food.

Is this metalic residue? If not, what is it?

Comment: Is there an exposed aluminium pan/pot bottom, maybe?

Comment: It's probably cardboard dust from the packaging.

Comment: This happens to my pots too sometimes, though mostly older ones.

Comment: @GdD Doesn't look cardboard at all, the residue has a dark grey metalic colour to it.

Comment: @rackandboneman The items I bought were made of stainless steel. They were brand new and hadn't come into contact with aluminium.

Comment: @Carmi If you use yours fingers, do you get a dark grey and metalic residue on them?

Comment: @samseva, I mostly get the residue on the counter-top as I'm washing the pot. It doesn't happen when the pot is dry, but only when wet on the outside. It does leave some residue on my fingers, but that washes off in plain water.

Answer (score 5):

It could be stainless steel and abrasive residue created from polishing.

> Method for Removal:
>
> Hand wiping with alkaline cleaners, followed by hot water rinsing.
>   May require multiple applications until wipe testing results are satisfactory.

http://www.ispeboston.org/files/july_2010_tech_talk.pdf

Answer (score 3):

As I said last week in the comments, I've been having this problem too, and I finally think I've worked it out.

It happens with my steel bottom pots and pans. It doesn't happen on my induction stove-top ever. It only ever happens when I use them on the electric, metal-top stove.

Basically, it seems to be metal/rust residue from the electric stove-top, rather than anything from the pot itself. Taking a cleaning rag over the stove-top gets the same gray residue.

It seems we both need a better quality stove.

Answer (score 0):

it is a food safe silicone,used as a manufacturing process coating

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Do you have any more information on this, including a reference?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this with a stainless steel water resevoir and have read on other sites that it is a form of oxidation, "chromium rust". I do not have any scientific research references backing this claim, but I can say that in my experience it appeared on a metal boiler that was clean and over time developed this after being exposed to nothing but heated water and air repeatedly. A haze had formed and when wiped with a clean paper towel showed to be a black-gray residue. It cleaned off again to where wiping with a clean towel showed no sign of the residue.