# Lead residue on stainless steel skewer?

Tags: food-safety, stainless-steel

I recently purchased some stainless steel kabob skewers from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MHRP2S6), similar to the ones listed [here](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/10-stainless-steel-skewer-pack/40710RS.html) at the Webstaurant Store.

[image]

They look and feel like stainless steel, however they appear to have some kind of coating. The surface of my skewers looks slightly more dull and grey than my stainless steel cookware.

Furthermore, I observed a dark grey residue coming off my skewers under the following circumstances:

1. Straight out of the box if I rub my fingers across the surface.
2. After putting them through the dishwasher if I rub my fingers across the surface.
3. After dishwasher if I rub a white tissue across the surface.

I noticed that there is also a Prop 65 warning listed in the Webstaurant link above, which states:

> WARNING: This product can expose you to chemicals including **lead**, which are known to the State of California to cause cancer, birth defects, or other reproductive harm. For more information, go to [www.p65warnings.ca.gov](http://www.p65warnings.ca.gov).

Is it likely that my skewers are indeed coated in something, and if so, what is this coating and why is it possible to contain lead?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/75734/dark-grey-residue-from-newly-purchased-stainless-steel-kitchen-items

Comment: Related too… assuming you don't fall asleep reading it ;-) https://ofmpub.epa.gov/apex/guideme_ext/f?p=guideme:gd:0::::gd:lead_guidance_3_1

Comment: How about a photo of your actual skewers, since apparently you didn't purchase them at webrestaurantstore?

Comment: Also: I don't think the Prop 65 warning is meaningful.  Looks like they put it on all of their metal utensil listings.

Comment: Any chance they're aluminum instead of steel? Because aluminum + dishwasher = ugly grey oxidation/coating that can rub off on your fingers.

Comment: That coating suggests that they might be zinc galvanized stainless. That'd account for the gray stuff, but lead is sometimes used to make melted zinc more fluid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-dip_galvanization

Comment: @FuzzyChef, I added a photo and the original purchase link.

Comment: @Marti, the material is SS according to the original listing, and I'm fairly its weight is that of SS.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, thanks, good point. I think this zinc galvanization is a likely candidate, because I don't think it's normal for brand new stainless steel to give off dark grey dust even after washing it.

Comment: @N4v It's standard for third party sellers on Amazon to lie about their products. The fact that the listing says "stainless steel" does not mean that it's actually stainless steel. Based on the residue, I'm guessing galvanized or aluminized carbon steel.

Comment: Someone wanna put the "lied about metal" as an answer?

Comment: @Sneftel , are you aware of anything I can do to test whether my product is indeed stainless steel or some other galvanized or aluminized steel?

Comment: It's worth noting that California's Prop. 65 regulations are quite strict, which has led to many (sometimes unnecessary) warnings. For example, if these items were manufactured in a place that might also handle lead-based products, and it's *possible* that some lead dust *might* get on them, a manufacturer might slap on a warning like this just in case some test shows up positive. In that case, a simple wash might get rid of residue. I don't know about this specific case, but I'd just note the warning may or may not be meaningful (and may or may not have anything to do with the coating).

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough if it is lead which I greatly doubt : Put the stainless on a grill ( outside) and heat to just dim red ( 1100 to 1200 F) . Any lead will  have long since evaporated  and the stainless will get a tight grey oxide coating (at most), depending on the time it is hot. Of course anything organic will also be gone.

Comment: Are there any alternatives if one doesn't own a grill? Would an oven suffice?

Comment: Some hardware stores sell lead test kits that should work on metal: https://www.epa.gov/lead/lead-test-kits

Comment: Domestic ovens don't get much above 600 F, not enough to boil lead. Maybe the dark material is a lubricant from the metal forming .

Comment: I would think a steel wool scouring pad could take off anything other than electro plating and I never heard of electroplating SS  ( with lead, zinc, aluminum, etc).